# ArrowNotImplementedError: halffloat error on applying pandas.to_feather on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I have a dataframe with columns of different datatypes including dates. No after doing some modifications, i want to save it a feather file so as to access it later. But i am getting the error on the following step

```
historical_transactions.to_feather('tmp/historical-raw')

ArrowNotImplementedError: halffloat
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess, in your dataframe, there is columns of `dtype` as `float16` which is not supported in feather format. you can convert those columns to `float32` and try.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
    historical_transactions.astype('float32').to_feather('tmp/historical-raw')
```

Note that above line could fail if you also have fields that are not convertable into float32. In order to ignore those columns and leave them as they are, try:

```
    historical_transactions.astype('float32', errors='ignore').to_feather('tmp/historical-raw')
```

Feather format depends on Pyarrow which in turn depends on the Apache Parquet format. Regarding float formats, it only supports float (32) and double (64). Not sure how big of a deal this is for you but there is also an open request to automatically "Coerce Arrow half-precision float to float32" in GitHub.

See [here](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1403) for details.

Comment: Feather and Apache Parquet are two distinct formats.

Answer (score 4):

Improving on Kocas' answer, converting exclusively the half-float columns

```
half_floats = historical_transactions.select_dtypes(include="float16")
historical_transactions[half_floats.columns] = half_floats.astype("float32")
historical_transactions.to_feather('tmp/historical-raw')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another work-around is to view `float16` as `uint16` on save and view `uint16` as `float16` on load. E.g.:

```
import numpy as np


def encode_float16_to_uint16(f16):
    return np.frombuffer(f16.astype(np.float16, copy=False), dtype=np.uint16)


def decode_uint16_to_float16(u16):
    return np.frombuffer(u16.astype(np.uint16, copy=False), dtype=np.float16)
```

`numpy.frombuffer` creates a view into the original object, hence, no data copy is involved when viewing `float16` array as `uint16` and vice versa. This work-around is as cheap as it gets.